# How To Get All Class Values Except $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to iterate through all slider values within class entry_percent, excluding the current selected slider.

No matter how I try it, I can't filter out the current selected slider?

What am I missing...

Here's the code...
(commented out is some of what I've tried)....

```
// get total of sliders other then current
        function sum_sliders() {
            var sum=0;
            var total=0;

            //var sliders = $('.entry_percent:not(this)');// get every slider other then the current

            //var sliders = $('.entry_percent').not(this);

            //var sliders = $('.entry_percent:not(this)');

            //var sliders = $('.entry_percent:not(this)'

            // var sliders = $('.entry_percent:not').(this);

            var sliders = $('.entry_percent').not(this);


            //iterate through each input and add to sum
            $(sliders).each(function() {

                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                console.log('Sum sliders value: '+ sum);

            });

            return(sum);

        }
```

Comment: Your question is completely incomprehensible. How does your HTML look? What do you mean by "class values except $(this)" (the two things don't have any connection at all).

Comment: Where are you using `sum_sliders` function?

Comment: How the *"current selected slider"* is different from the others? Maybe has special class, e.g. `.active` or so? `this` in your example may refer to anything, not a particular object.

Comment: ..how do you call sum_sliders() function

Comment: What is "this" at sum_sliders() context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `this` where you are looking for it. You must pass `this` to the function like so:

```
function sum_sliders() {
     var sum=0, total=0;
     var sliders = $('.entry_percent').not(this);
     //iterate through each input and add to sum
     $(sliders).each(function() {
         sum += parseFloat(this.value);
         console.log('Sum sliders value: '+ sum);
     });
     return(sum);
 }
 $("#elementYouClickToCallFunction").click(sum_sliders); //Instead of using an anonymous function
```

There's also -- from what you provided -- no reason not to simply include the contents of `sum_sliders` inside the click-bound anonymous function:

```
$("#elementYouClickToCallFunction").click(function(){
     var sum=0, total=0;
     var sliders = $('.entry_percent').not(this);
     //iterate through each input and add to sum
     $(sliders).each(function() {
         sum += parseFloat(this.value);
         console.log('Sum sliders value: '+ sum);
     });
     return(sum);
 });
```

Comment: If you call the function like so: `$('#elementYouClick').click(sum_sliders)` jQuery (from memory) will pass the clicked-element as the `this` to the function.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, fixed.

Comment: Rookie mistake I made.  Thanks for the enlightenment.